# How to set constraint for UIView to appear below the status bar in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, constraints

Here is the case: I have a nib file with a custom `UIToolbar`. I load this nib file in my `UINavigationController` (so it will appear everywhere while the user is using the app). However, when I add the subview, it appears **UNDER** the status bar. And since I am new with Swift and constraints, I need your help, people :)

Here is my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad();

    var statusBarHeight = UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarFrame.size.height

    var toolbarView = self.loadFromNibNamed("toolbarView")!

    toolbarView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false);

    self.view.addSubview(toolbarView);
    self.view.bringSubviewToFront(toolbarView);
    let statusBarConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: toolbarView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, multiplier: 1, constant: statusBarHeight)

    self.view.addConstraint(statusBarConstraint)
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func loadFromNibNamed(nibNamed: String, bundle : NSBundle? = nil) -> UIView? {
    return UINib(
        nibName: nibNamed,
        bundle: bundle
        ).instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)[0] as? UIView
}
```

How to set my subview to appear right bellow the status bar using `NSLayoutConstraint` instead of changing the frame's origin.y?